# Calculating standard deviation of power law regression going to infinity

Tags: fitting, warning-messages, nonlinear

So, i have a dataset which behaviour could be approached by the power law:

$$ N(x)= a - bx^{-1/c} $$

So i am doing this to get the regression:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a - b*x^(-1/c), {{a, 0}, {b, 0}, {c,2}}, x, MaxIterations -> \[Infinity]]
```

So i get the following result:

[image]

Then i get these standard deviations for a, b, c:

[image]

Now i am using the gaussian law for error propagation to calculate the standard deviation of N(x):

```
\[Sqrt]((D[a - b*x^(-1/c), a]*11426.108699236138`)^2 + (D[a - b*x^(-1/c), b]*1.434690881054167`*^8)^2 + (D[a - b*x^(-1/c),c]*0.03626373539623972`)^2)

a = 3.2763042912759576`*^6;
b = 1.4018942844796562`*^9;
c = 2.320026692762461`;
```

Then i am getting the resulting function:

[image]

When i plot the resulting function sigma N(x), i am getting this graph:

[image]

So the error term is declines for x going to infinity.

Now my goal is to get the standard deviation for:

$$ x \rightarrow \infty $$

So i have done this:

[image]

So i am not that experienced in error calculations, and i am not sure if my action was right. I would be thankful if somebody could have a look on it.

Comment: With `NonlinearModelFit` you are fitting $N(x)=a−b x^{−1/c} + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.  In other words,
how you include the residual error is critical. Do the observed residuals support such an error structure?  Are you
looking for an estimate of the limit as $x\rightarrow \infty$ of $SE(\hat{a}-\hat{b} x^{-1/\hat{c}})$ (standard error of the mean prediction) or 
$SE(\hat{a}-\hat{b} x^{-1/\hat{c}}+\epsilon)$ (standard error of a single prediction)?

Comment: Once you have determined the appropriate error structure, you can have *Mathematica* do all of the work for you as it will calculate `MeanPredictionBands` and `SinglePredictionBands`.  From those equations you can extract the associated standard errors.

Comment: @JimB Thank you, this helped! I think I am looking for for an estimate of the standard error of a single prediction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After thinking about this I think it's much simpler than I indicated in the comments.

The prediction for a single value of $x$ is $\hat{a}+\hat{b} x^{-1/\hat{c}}+\epsilon$.  The limit of that prediction as $x\rightarrow \infty$ is $\hat{a}+\epsilon$ which you can check with the following command:

[image: Limit of prediction]

So you'd want to find the variance of $\hat{a}+\epsilon$ which is estimated to be

```
nlm["CovarianceMatrix"][[1, 1]] + nlm["EstimatedVariance"]
```

The more complicated approach I gave in the comments should get you the same number.